# qsort-C standard library-how to send a compare function with non const args?

Tags: c, qsort

Im working on a homework project.
I need to implement a generic List accoarding to a header that the staff created.
They had defined compare functions in the header like this:

```
typedef int(*CompareListElements)(ListElement, ListElement);
```

(ListElement=void*)

I am trying to use qsort from the standard library, but I can't compile the program because the compare function I'm trying to pass to `qsort` is getting non const arguments.
Is there a way to pass it anyway?
Thanks ahead.

The function im trying to implement:

```
ListResult listSort(List list, CompareListElements compareElement) {
    CHECK_RETURN(((list == NULL)||(compareElement == NULL)),LIST_NULL_ARGUMENT);
    int size=0;
    ListElement* elementArray=listToArray(list, &size);
    CHECK_RETURN((elementArray == NULL), LIST_OUT_OF_MEMORY);
    qsort(elementArray, size, sizeof(*elementArray), compareElement);
    returnArrayToList(list,elementArray);
    return LIST_SUCCESS;
}
```

The error:
passing argument 4 of 'qsort' from incompatible pointer type

Comment: A compare function should not change its parameters, can you modify the code?

Comment: Show the code please and we will try to work the solution out together. Generally the `compar` function should take `const` pointers, not elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the compare function I am trying to use qsort from the standard library

**Not nice, try to avoid this:**

Just wrap up the compare function into another function that is accepted by the compiler to be passed to `qsort()`.

Inside the wrapper you can then use the Casting-Hammer to fit things ... ;-)

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef void* ListElement;
typedef int(*CompareListElements)(ListElement, ListElement);

CompareListElements c =  ... /* Initialise properly here. */

int cmp(const void * pv1, const void * pv2)
{
  return c((ListElement)pv1, (ListElement)pv2); /* Hammering here ... */
}


int main(void)  
{
  int a[4] = {3, 0, 2, 1};
  qsort(a, sizeof *a, 4, cmp);
}
```

---

Referring your edit providing the implementation of `listSort()`, you could still use the workaround I propose above by using the GNU extension function [`qsort_r()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html):

```
int cmp_r(const void * pv1, const void * pv2, void * pv)
{
  CompareListElements c_r = pv;
  return c_r((ListElement)pv1, (ListElement)pv2); /* Still hammering here ... */
}

ListResult listSort(List list, CompareListElements compareElement) 
{
  ...

  qsort_r(elementArray, size, sizeof(*elementArray), cmp_r, compareElement);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks but I think It will not help me because it's a problem to wrap the  compare function since I will have to send another argument to the function listSort..

Comment: @NiranDokhanian: Please see the update to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This example shows how to use the arguments in `compare()` provided for `qsort`. It casts the `const void*` pointer to the type you are comparing. Note that I could have returned the simple difference between the two numbers, but in some instances that can cause undefined behaviour when the difference "wraps".

You said little about your linked list, so I stuck to the question title, about `qsort()`. The reason it takes `const` pointers is to prevent your `compare()` function from altering the data directly: it returns a value based on reading the data values. Obviously the data itself cannot be `const` otherwise `qsort()` won't be able to manipulate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARRSIZE  10

struct numarr {
    int numb;
    struct numarr *next;
    };

struct numarr array [ARRSIZE];

int compare( const void *arg1, const void *arg2 )
{
    if (((struct numarr*)arg1)->numb > ((struct numarr*)arg2)->numb)
        return 1;
    if (((struct numarr*)arg1)->numb < ((struct numarr*)arg2)->numb)
        return -1;
    return 0;
}    

int main() {
    int i;
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    // set up a random array
    printf ("Unsorted: ");
    for(i=0; i<ARRSIZE; i++){
        array[i].numb = rand() % ARRSIZE;
        printf ("%d ", array[i].numb);
    }
    printf ("%\n");

    // sort and print the array
    qsort (array, ARRSIZE, sizeof(struct numarr), compare);
    printf ("Sorted:   ");
    for(i=0; i<ARRSIZE; i++){
        printf ("%d ", array[i].numb);
    }
    printf ("%\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Program output

```
Unsorted: 8 7 3 0 7 5 9 2 0 0
Sorted:   0 0 0 2 3 5 7 7 8 9
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks but I think I didn't explain myself well.. 
I added my code now.. I hope you will understand. the difference is mainly in the defenition of the pointer to the compare function..

Comment: No worries, I realised that after reading the answer from @alk